# How to execute code in intellij frame by frame?

Tags: intellij-idea

I am using a library that has a bug. But I don't know the inner workings of this library, so I can't put a breakpoint ahead of time. What I want to do is for intellij to break at every stackframe automatically, without me having to put breakpoints, is it possible to do that?